# Click an item in ListBox1 and ListBox2 item is also selected simultaneously in vb

Tags: vb.net, select, listbox

Basically when i have 2 listboxes, when u select an item in the listbox it gets highlighted.

What i want to be able to do is select an item from whatever listbox and it highlights the corresponding data.

This is what iv'e tried, but obviously this is just a loop which crashes the program.

```
Private Sub lstOrders_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstOrders.SelectedIndexChanged
    lstTotalsEachOrder.SetSelected(lstOrders.SelectedIndex, True)
End Sub
Private Sub lstTotalsEachOrder_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstTotalsEachOrder.SelectedIndexChanged
    lstOrders.SetSelected(lstTotalsEachOrder.SelectedIndex, True)
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: you could set a boolean that controls the calls to `SetSelected`.

Comment: @DanielA.White sorry, could you show me how to do that

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment on your previous question, this would be simpler if you used a ListView, then all the related data would be in a different subitems of the same item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a boolean flag.

```
Dim Selecting As Boolean = False
Private Sub lstOrders_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstOrders.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Not Selecting Then
       Selecting = True
       lstTotalsEachOrder.SetSelected(lstOrders.SelectedIndex, True)
       Selecting = False
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub lstTotalsEachOrder_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstTotalsEachOrder.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Not Selecting Then
       Selecting = True
       lstOrders.SetSelected(lstTotalsEachOrder.SelectedIndex, True)
       Selecting = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I found a problem, if i try an remove items using the following code lstOrders.Items.RemoveAt(lstOrders.Items.Count - 1), lstOrders.Items.RemoveAt(lstOrders.Items.Count - 1). Its fine until it reaches a selected item and an error is thrown for the code above

Comment: @leuan you should ask a separate question in that case

Answer (score 2):

Just keep a flag to know when you're "handling yourself" the selection

```
Private isManuallyHandled As Boolean = False

Private Sub ListBoxes_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstOrders.SelectedIndexChanged, lstTotalsEachOrder.SelectedIndexChanged
    If isManuallyHandled Then Return

    Dim source = DirectCast(sender, ListBox)
    Dim target = If(source Is lstOrders, lstTotalsEachOrder, lstOrders)
    isManuallyHandled = True
    target.SelectedIndex = source.SelectedIndex ' simpler than SetSelected
    isManuallyHandled = False
End Sub
```